# Different F1 scores for different preprocessing techniques- sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics

I am building a classification model using `sklearn's GradientBoostingClassifier`. For the same model, I tried different preprocessing techniques: `StandarScaler, Scale, and Normalizer` on the same data but I am getting different `f1_scores` each time. For `StandardScaler`, it is highest and lowest for `Normalizer`. Why is it so? Is there any other technique for which I can get an even higher score?

Comment: Please paste your code and the details of what preprocessing steps you did. Keep the question specific. It'll boost your odds of getting a good response.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in their respective definitions:

- StandardScaler: Standardize features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance
- Normalizer: Normalize samples individually to unit norm.
- Scale: Standardize a dataset along any axis. Center to the mean and component wise scale to unit variance.

The data used to fit your model will change, so will the F1 score.

Here is a useful link comparing different scalers : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-all-scaling-py